# To peek() or not to peek()

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue, peek

I have PriorityQueue use example which produces

```
3

1

1

1

5

0
```

This is the code

```
import java.util.*;

class Someclass
{

public static class IntegerWr 
    implements Comparable<IntegerWr>
{
    Integer val;

    IntegerWr(Integer val)
    {
        this.val = val; 
    }

    public void change(Integer nval)
    { 
        this.val = nval;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(IntegerWr iw)
    {
        return val.compareTo(iw.val);
    }
    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return ""+val;
    }
}
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        PriorityQueue<IntegerWr> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        pq.add(new IntegerWr(3));
        System.out.println(pq.peek());
        IntegerWr iw1 = new IntegerWr(1);        
        pq.add(iw1);
        System.out.println(pq.peek());
        pq.add(new IntegerWr(4));
        System.out.println(pq.peek());
        pq.add(new IntegerWr(2));
        System.out.println(pq.peek()); //must output 1, and does so
        iw1.change(5);                 //change value of element that is actually on peek
        System.out.println(pq.peek()); //outputs 5 which is unexpected
        pq.add(new IntegerWr(0));
        System.out.println(pq.peek()); 
    }
}
```

Seems like the PriorityQueue orders only on insert. What method to use to get the actual peek()?

Comment: "*Seems like the PriorityQueue orders only on insert.*"--it definitely does. How can the queue know that you modify some element? For example, if you add items to a list, then sort it, then change some of its value so order becomes broken, wouldn't you expect that it is somehow considered by the list?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PriorityQueue is an implementation of the Queue. If we look at the [Queue interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll()) it has methods peek(), poll(), remove().

`peek()` method returns, but does not remove, the head of the queue.

`poll()` method removes and return the head of the queue. Exactly which element is removed from the queue is a function of the **queue's ordering** policy.

```
import java.util.*;

class Someclass
{

public static class IntegerWr 
    implements Comparable<IntegerWr>
{
    Integer val;

    IntegerWr(Integer val)
    {
        this.val = val; 
    }

    public void change(Integer nval)
    { 
        this.val = nval;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(IntegerWr iw)
    {
        return val.compareTo(iw.val);
    }
    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return ""+val;
    }
}
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        PriorityQueue<IntegerWr> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        pq.add(new IntegerWr(3));
        System.out.println(pq.peek());
        IntegerWr iw1 = new IntegerWr(1);        
        pq.add(iw1);
        System.out.println(pq.peek());
        pq.add(new IntegerWr(4));
        System.out.println(pq.peek());
        pq.add(new IntegerWr(2));
        System.out.println(pq.peek()); //must output 1, and does so
        iw1.change(5);                 //change value of element that is actually on peek
        System.out.println(pq.peek()); //outputs 5 which is unexpected
        pq.add(new IntegerWr(0));
        System.out.println(pq.peek()); 

        System.out.println("Elements ordered");
        Object o = null;
        while ((o = pq.poll()) != null) //poll() method removes and return
                                        //the head of the queue.
                                        //Exactly which element is removed 
                                        //from the queue is a function 
                                        //of the queue's ordering policy
        {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
3

1

1

1

5

0

Elements ordered

0

2

3

4

5
```

To get elements of PriorityQueue **in order** use `poll()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing a value INSIDE the object stored in the queue.
The queue does not know anything about the contents of the objects.
So when you call a method on an object in the queue (as in 'iw1.change(5)'), nothing in the queue knows about it.
You need to store a replacement object, for the queue to re-order the elements.

Comment: it will be okay to `poll()` the item, modify it and `offer()` it back to the queue to keep correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `iw1.change(5);` do:

```
pq.remove(iw1);
iw1.change(5);
pq.add(iw1);
```

Comment: The change of the object happens at some time. The priority queue is built once and lives longer. The change() might occur at any time later. If objects are changed the PriorityQueue peek() doesn't give correct (by means of natural ordering of the objects stored) result. :/

Comment: @willmore the same applies to all kinds of collections in java that have some kind of ordering , you cannot change properties of the object that makes up the ordering criteria once you've added an object to such a collection. (and that applies even to some collections such as Maps that don't have a particular ordering)